# How to handle download pop up window using Python and get the file saved?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a link, which contains downloadble file,now when i am putting that link onto the browser, and hit `ENTER` a popup window is coming to download. Now using Python can we save that file in local machine?

say downloadable link :

```
https://xyz.test.com/aems/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=8120070&cs=LU31NT9us5P9Pvkb1BrtdwaCrEraskiCJcY6E2ucP5s.xyz
```

**Code**

it is for preparing the link: but finally i couldn't find a way how to handle this:

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', {"style": "display:inline; position:relative;"}, href=True):
    href = a['href'].strip()
    href = "https://xyz.test.com/" + href
print(href)
```

[Download window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nIcZ.png)

Comment: Is the popup a browser window, or an OS-based save dialog?  If it's a save dialog, it's out of scope for Selenium and you'll have to use a library for driving the OS, or find a way to emulate the activity in a platform independent way.

Comment: @sr2222 I didn't get your point,still my answer is yes the Pop-up is a browser window which has three options - `save`,`Save As` and `Cancel`.

Comment: @sr2222 I have given the downloaded window link,updated my description!

Comment: you can do it with python framework `PyQt4`

Comment: If you are using Selenium, you can get around the dialog box by editing your `browser_prefs` to never prompt you for a downloads of a certain type.

Comment: Okay then download the file is my `goal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is not to test the *download popup* itself, but the existence/content of the file, you can download it using urllib:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve(href, filename)
```

You would need to add the necesary exception handling (to make sure the URL really points to something) and the file processing once downloaded to verify it's content.

Comment: `Filename` can not be provided,but the download link is possible.`filename` is dynamic.